# get filename and extension of files in hdfs with Python

Tags: python, hadoop

Is there an equivalent of the `os` module in Python do read the filesystem (hadoop 2.6)?

In particular I am interested about getting extension of a file and base name (not including the full path).

Comment: Why do you need an equivalent to the `os` module ? It should work without a problem with the hadoop mounted filesystem. Have you tried anything that didn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

No need for "*an equivalent*", `os.path.basename` is exactly the same for `hdfs`.

i.e.:

```
import os.path as path
print path.basename("/path/to/file.txt")
# file.txt
```

---

[os.path — Common pathname manipulations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

Comment: But the dirname may be different from locally setting, as hadoop container may have a different dirname with temporary containers.